# Bootstrap @media min-width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

Trying to add my custom media query :

```
@media (min-width: 1120px) {
   .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        right: 0;
        left: auto;
    }
   .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
        right: auto;
        left: 0;
   }
}
```

to bootstrap but the browser seems to take into account the minimum in bootstrap. I added the script after the bootstrap style declaration and still got the same behavior.

Comment: Your media query will not override bootstrap media query. if you want to do  that, you have to override the break-point in bootstrap, or redefining the class(give a new name to your css class).

Comment: I've got plenty of classes ...

Answer (score 3):

Look at [this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/#container-sizes). Particularly at `@container-large-desktop` variable value. Higher BootStrap window size is 1140px so you are specifying a mediaquery that apply only in a range of 20px

Comment: My 1120px value is just an example. Actually,  this value is dynamic. So I wonder how it will work in what ever value set.

Comment: With a Browser inspector, you can verify if some rules override yours. In this specific case, you have to declare them after if they have the same "specificity" or instead augment your customu rules specificity. Solution proposed by CreativePS could be an example.

Comment: I'll just change min-width values in bootstrap.css ! seems working even if changing  in bootstrap.css is bad ...